# Regex to Match Words and Numbers with Repeating Sequences (FOO-123 / FOO-456 /...etc)

Tags: regex

https://regexr.com/539me

I have a changelog that I need to look like this:

```
- [FOO-123] This is a change from one project
- [FOO-567 / FOO-890] This has two changes from one project
- [BAR-123 / BAZ-456 / BANG-1234 ] This has three changes from three different projects
```

I was satisfied with my current regex that I have, but then I started testing it further, and it messes up when I accidentally type typos or add a character like A from BAR to FOO to make FOA or missing a /:

```
- [FOB-1234] hello 
- [BAG-1234] how
- [FOO-1234 FOO-5678] are
- [FOA-1234 / BARG-1234 / BZF-1234] you?
```

How would I get it so that the top is always good but the bottom never works?

Regex I've currently created:

```
/-\s\[[(FOO|BAR|BAZ|BANG)-\d{\s}{/}{\s}+]*]\s.+/g
```

https://regexr.com/539me

Comment: Try `^-\s\[(?:FOO|BAR|BAZ|BANG)-\d+(?: / (?:FOO|BAR|BAZ|BANG)-\d+)*\] .+$` https://regex101.com/r/o1Muo8/1

Comment: Why this part ? `\d{\s}{/}{\s}+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match one of the alternatives and use an optionally repeating group prepended with a space, forward slash and space.

```
^-\s\[(?:FOO|BAR|BAZ|BANG)-\d+(?: / (?:FOO|BAR|BAZ|BANG)-\d+)*\] .+$
```

That will match

- `^` Start of string
- `\s\[` Match a whitespace char and `[`
- `(?:FOO|BAR|BAZ|BANG)` Match any of the alternatives
- `-\d+` Match `-` and 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `/ (?:FOO|BAR|BAZ|BANG)-\d+` Match  `/` , 1 or the alternatives and - plus 1+ digits
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `\] .+` Match `]`, space and 1+ occurrences of any char except a newline.
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o1Muo8/1)

Note to remove the `[` and `]` around the group or else it would make it a character class.